# How to sort a dataset by the hash of a column in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset` and trying to sort it by the hash of a column. Tried it like

```
ds.sort($"source".hashCode)
```

but it's obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the in-built function `hash` of the functions `package`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.hash

ds.sort(hash($"source"))
```

**Quick example**

INPUT

```
+--------+-----+
| source |other|
+--------+-----+
|       a|    3|
|       c|    2|
|       b|    2|
+--------+-----+
```

Output:

```
+------+-----+
|source|other|
+------+-----+
|     c|    2|
|     a|    3|
|     b|    2|
+------+-----+
```

Hash result in a column just for demostrative purposes:

```
+------+-----+-----------+
|source|other|       hash|
+------+-----+-----------+
|     c|    2|-2124386278|
|     a|    3| 1485273170|
|     b|    2| 1905031361|
+------+-----+-----------+
```